# Django NameError [app name] is not defined

Tags: python, django, django-grappelli

Trying to use django-grappelli for my admin theme, install has been surprisingly challenging. Running into the following in my urls.py:

```
NameError .. name 'grappelli' is not defined
```

The error is thrown on the line

```
(r'^grappelli/', include(grappelli.urls))
```

Installed grappelli with pip, and grappelli is in my sites-packages directory. Added to my `INSTALLED_APPS`, ran syncdb, tried adding grappelli to my pythonpath, but no luck.  If I import grappelli in urls.py the error changes to an `AttributeError - 'module' has no attribute 'urls'`

Suggestions or any kind of help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Line should read:

```
(r'^grappelli/', include('grappelli.urls'))
```

`include` either takes a path to a urls module OR it can be a python object that returns the url patterns
http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#include

So your two options are either the line above (path to urls) or

```
from grappelli.urls import urlpatterns as grappelli_urls

(r'^grappelli/', include(grappelli_urls)),
```

As for the error, it's one of the most straight forward errors in Python to debug: `grappelli` is not defined, as in.. it hasn't been defined.

Imagine being in the shell:

```
>>> print grappelli
exception: variable undefined
>>> grappelli = 'hello' # we just defined grappelli
>>> print grappelli
'hello'
```

Comment: Thanks @Yuji - I can't believe I didn't try that. It seemed like it should be obvious but I got tripped up when importing grappelli didn't give me any trouble.  Was assuming adding grappelli to my installed_apps gave me access to that object as variable.  Will accept as soon as it'll let me.

Comment: NP! I did notice that the grappelli docs suggest you `include(grappelli.urls)` :) wrong.

Comment: It's important to point out the the quotes around 'grappelli.urls' is what fixes this issue... for whatever reason.

Comment: Well, I'm not using grappelli, but I have the same error with another package. I tried importing the package and then referencing package.urls but that still did not work until I surrounded it with quotes and then I did not even need to import that package. Regardless, your answer and the one below provided a solution that works. :-)

Comment: I have encountered similar problem, but my solution is to change "chdir = /var/django/zhanxw/" to "chdir = /var/django/zhanxw" in my uWSGI conf file (removing the trailing slash). Hope this is helpful for someone.

Comment: ty. I forget this and I was surprised when seeing this soloution

Answer (score 11):

I realize this is over a year old, but it was one of the top results on Google when I was having this same problem.

Rather than importing urlpatterns from grapelli.urls, you can also change the include() statement

```
(r'^grappelli/', include(grappelli.urls))
```

to

```
(r'^grappelli/', include('grappelli.urls'))
```

This threw me off for a bit as well until I noticed the need for quoting the package.urls in the include statement.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to import the following in **urls.py**:

```
from django.conf.urls import include
```

Answer (score 2):

When declaring your routes, you forgot to quote an expression.

Replace `grappelli.urls` by `'grappelli.urls'` to make it work!

The correct syntax would then be:

```
(r'^grappelli/', include('grappelli.urls'))
```